# error when trying to use webrtcvad

Tags: python, voice-recognition

I am trying to do voice activity detection using webrtcvad 2.0.8. This [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webrtcvad](http://link) provides the basic procedure. When I try to implement it as follows, I get an error. 
my code:

```
import webrtcvad
from scipy.io import wavfile
import scipy
source1 = path + "phone1.wav"
fs, audio = wavfile.read(source1)
audio_n = audio/float(2**15)

vad = webrtcvad.Vad(3)
def audioSlice(x, fs, framesz, hop):
    framesamp = int(framesz*fs)
    hopsamp = int(hop*fs)
    X = scipy.array([x[i:i+framesamp] for i in range(0, len(x)-framesamp, hopsamp)])
    return X
framesz=10./1000 #10 ms 
hop = 1.0*framesz
Z = audioSlice(audio_n, fs, framesz, hop)
vad.is_speech(Z[100], fs)
```

The error that I get is:

```
is_speech(self, buf, sample_rate, length)
     25                 'buffer has %s frames, but length argument was %s' % (
     26                     int(len(buf) / 2.0), length))
---> 27         return _webrtcvad.process(self._vad, sample_rate, buf, length)
     28 
     29 

Error: Error while processing frame
```

Comment: webrtc vad supports only 10ms frames

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev Z[100] is 10 ms (framesz=10/1000). the comment beside it was a mistake

Comment: webrtcvad supports frames of 10 ms, 20 ms or 30 ms.

Comment: As the README mentions, "The WebRTC VAD only accepts 16-bit mono PCM audio, sampled at 8000, 16000, 32000 or 48000 Hz. A frame must be either 10, 20, or 30 ms in duration."

For example, if your sample rate is 16000 Hz, then the only allowed frame/chunk sizes are 16000 * ({10,20,30} / 1000) = 160, 320 or 480 samples. Since each sample is 2 bytes (16 bits), the only allowed frame/chunk sizes are 320, 640, or 960 bytes.

This is a restriction of the underlying webrtc library, not the python wrapper.
https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad/issues/30#issuecomment-468741943

Answer (score 6, accepted):

webrtcvad expects buffer to be a string with data bytes, not an array of floats. You can do something like

```
fr = np.int16(Z[100] * 32768).tobytes()
vad.is_speech(fr, fs)
```